# Register all IMediatR classes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mediatr

Is there any form to avoid registering all the assemblies that implement IMediator service?

I try using these options but none of them helps me:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
```

Currently the only option that works for me is if I register all the services like this:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(MYQUERY).Assembly));
```

But this is very tedious because my program.cs will have a lot of lines, is there any other option to do this?

Comment: So you have a lot of assemblies that contain mediator services and you want to register them all?

Comment: Yes, I would like to register all of them avoiding include them manually in the program.cs, but I dont know if there is any other option.

Comment: I found that If I register only one of these assemblies the other will work fine, but I dont like it because must be a better option.

Comment: _"I found that If I register only one of these assemblies the other will work fine"_ - sounds very suspicious. Are you sure that the mediator services are in different assemblies? Maybe you are confusing assemblies with something else (like namespaces)? Can you please share the full [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this is very tedious because my program.cs will have a lot of lines

Personally I would go with the "manual" approach. If you don't want to "litter" the Program.cs then you can always move this part of the setup to some extension method:

```cs
public static class MediatrRegistrationExts
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMediatorWithAll(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var types = new[]
        {
            typeof(MediatrAssemlyOneLandmark),
            typeof(MediatrAssemlyTwoLandmark)
        };
        services.AddMediatR(types.Select(t => t.Assembly).ToArray());
        return services;
    }
}
```

And then:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMediatorWithAll();
```

But if you really-really want to go full dynamic mode then you can try something like the following (not tested):

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(GetAllAssemblies().ToArray());

static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAllAssemblies()
{
    var assemblies = new HashSet<string>();
    var stack = new Stack<Assembly>();

    stack.Push(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var asm = stack.Pop();

        yield return asm;

        foreach (var reference in asm.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            if (!assemblies.Contains(reference.FullName))
            {
                stack.Push(Assembly.Load(reference));
                assemblies.Add(reference.FullName);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But I highly recommend against it.

P.S.

Make sure that you have actually those types placed in different assemblies because based on the comments it is highly likely they are actually in a single assembly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I came across with your first option and it works pretty fine, but maybe I'm missing something. 

My project contain two layers, the first one where the program.cs is located and the second one with the queries, etc... 

If I dont register any of my queries I could not use any one, but If I register my QUERY1 this allow me to use my QUERY2 (even when I didnt register it)

Comment: @J003_ I suspect that there is a slight misunderstanding in the terminology on your side. If both queries are in the same project (i.e. C# project) they will be in the same assembly. The code in question will register all appropriate types from the same assembly. Try checking the assemblies full names for both types, I pretty much sure that you will see the same value.

Comment: Yeah you was right, I need the dll of the project where the query were located, so only using builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(typeof(QUERY1).Assembly); works because all my queries are located in the same project.